# Battery Powered LED Light Delay

Tags: light, delay

I’ve created an airgun bell target and attached an led light to it which lights up for just a second when the target is hit.  However, I was wondering if there was an easy way to make the light stay on for a few seconds longer with some type of delay. I know nothing about electrical engineering so I maybe over my head already.

I’m using a push button led light from the auto section a Walmart which uses 4 AA batteries.  I cut the push button off and attached one wire to the bell and the other to the paddle.  When the paddle hits the bell the bell dings and the light lights up.

[image: Bell Target Light On]

[image: Bell Target Top]

Comment: look up 555 timer one-shot mode

Answer (score 0):

What id use is a 555 in monostable vibrator mode.

Comprehensive information here and obv Google: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html

Quick, simple and cheap. Should be pretty reliable and a great starter project for someone new to electronics...

If you use a pot for the timing resistor, you will be able to adjust the on time :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your construction, add 6.3V 10,000uF across the LED first and see whether you prefer the delay. If you still find it too short then it's better to use another circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzMOEx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>